# RED5 - cannot call RED5 method/ function from flash client Air for IOS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, red5

I have a NetConnection in flash client that connects to the RED5 server with no problems but when i want to call a RED5 method/ function i keep get this error:

I have set the nc.client = this, but still i get an error.

```
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property perform not found on HUGT and there is no default value.
Error #2044: Unhandled AsyncErrorEvent:. text=Error #2095: flash.net.NetConnection was unable    to invoke callback perform. error=ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property perform not    found on HUGT and there is no default value.
at HUGT/setUpRed5Connection()[/Users/trikampatel/Documents/fb/HUGT.as:89]
at HUGT/onAddedToStage()[/Users/trikampatel/Documents/fb/HUGT.as:175]
```

The code I'm using is below:

```
    private function setUpRed5Connection(){
        nc = new NetConnection();
        nc.client = this;       
        nc.connect("rtmp://192.168.1.4/RED5Hugt");
        nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,getStream);
    }

    public function onBWCheck(...rest):Number
    { 
        return 0; 
    } 

    public function onBWDone(...rest):void
    { 
        var p_bw:Number; 
        if (rest.length > 0){
            p_bw = rest[0]; 
        }
        trace("bandwidth = " + p_bw + " Kbps."); 
    }  

    function getStream(e:NetStatusEvent):void
    {

        //connectCamera();
        nsIn = new NetStream(nc); 
        nsOut = new NetStream(nc); 

        //vid.attachNetStream(nsIn);
        //nsIn.play("tester");

        //nsOut=new NetStream(nc);
        //netOut.attachAudio(mic);
        //nsOut.attachCamera(cam);
        //nsOut.publish("tester", "live");


    }

    public function performSend(country:String, uid:String):void{

        trace("cdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdcdc");

        var nr:Responder = new Responder(netResponderHandler);
        nc.call("perform", nr, uid, country);

    }

    function netResponderHandler(serverResult:Object)
    {
        trace("The result is " + serverResult);
    }
```

RED5 server:

```
public long perform(Object[] params){

    System.out.println((String)params[0] + " " + (String) params[1]);



    User u = this.getCountryPerformer(country).getUser(uid);
    long yt = u.ticket;



    return yt;

}
```

### UPDATE

Unusual behaviour now, i created a perform function in my action script class and the nc.call("perform", nr, val, val2) is calling the perform method in my action script class rather than the perform method in the red5 application adapter class, here is the function i created that gets called in the action script:

```
    public function perform(obj:Object, obj2:Object){
        trace("dzddzdzd");
    }
```

Comment: I changed the nc.client = this to nc.client = { onBWDone: function():void{} }; and now the error does not occur but the call var nr:Responder = new Responder(netResponderHandler);nc.call("perform", nr, uid, country); does not do anything

Comment: @Mondain, hi i wonder if you could help me with this, thanks.